# Terraform : cannot apply a version constraint to module "kms" because it has a relative local path

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create google KMS resource using Terraform as

```
module "kms" {
  source = "./modules/kms"
  version = "~> 0.1"
  providers = {
    google = google.impersonated
  }
  project_id = var.project_id
  location = "global"
  keyring_name = "${var.environment}-keyring"
  key_name = "${var.environment}-key"
}
```

Resource definition inside kms module

```
resource "google_kms_key_ring" "key_ring" {
  name = var.keyring_name
  project = var.project_id
  location = var.location
}

resource "google_kms_crypto_key" "key" {
  name = var.key_name
  location = var.location
  key_ring = google_kms_key_ring.key_ring.self_link
}
```

Running Terraform init throws up error as :

```
Cannot apply a version constraint to module "kms" (at main.tf:165) because it has a relative local path.
```

Directory structure

```
|--Terraform
   |-- main.tf
   |-- variable.tf
   |-- output.tf
   |-- ...
   |-- modules
       |-- kms
           |-- main.tf
           |-- variable.tf
           |-- output.tf
```

Terraform version is `~> 0.12.15`

How to fix this error ?

Comment: Don't set the version constraint on the module. This is only used for modules in the Terraform registry, not local modules.

Comment: Thanks. Removing version resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had cloned a sql-db module from the terraform registry but did not remove the version in the module block.

This is the expected module block

```
module "sql-db" {
  source  = "GoogleCloudPlatform/sql-db/google//modules/mssql"
  version = "4.0.0"
}
```

This is what I had (which caused this error)

```
module "sql-db" {
  //Replaced registry uri with a relative path and hence the error.
  source  = "./modules/mssql"
  version = "4.0.0"
}
```

So the solution could have been one of two ways

1. Keep registry uri path and retain the version

```
module "sql-db" {
  source  = "GoogleCloudPlatform/sql-db/google//modules/mssql"
  version = "4.0.0"
}
```

**OR**

2. Keep relative path and remove the version

```
module "sql-db" {
  //Replaced registry uri with a relative path and hence the error.
  source  = "./modules/mssql"
}
```